# Make JSON in the proper format for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Following is my JSON data returned by Response:

> [{"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":5}, {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":8}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":9}, {"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":15}, {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":3}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":5}, {"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":3}, , {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":10}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":11}]

Please how can I get  the proper format to draw charts (Highcharts) using jquery or javascript as below:

```
series: [{
    name: 'AAA',
    data: [5, 15, 3]

}, {
    name: 'BBB',
    data: [8, 3, 10]

}, {
    name: 'CCC',
    data: 9, 5, 11]

}]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service as outlined in the [help]. The objective is for you to do the basic research and others help you fix **your code** when it doen't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a temporary object, where you store each group by `name`, then convert that object to array via `map()`:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":5}, {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":8}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":9}, {"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":15}, {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":3}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":5}, {"id":1,"name":"AAA","value":3}, , {"id":1,"name":"BBB","value":10}, {"id":1,"name":"CCC","value":11}];

const temp = {};
data.forEach(row => {
  if (!temp[row.name]) {
    temp[row.name] = { name: row.name, data: [] };
  }
  
  temp[row.name].data.push(row.value);
});

const series = {
  series: Object.keys(temp).map(name => ({ name, data: temp[name].data })),
};

console.log(series);
```